# Why is the change of property value "management.endpoint.health.show-details" ignored at runtime?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-consul

I'm using Spring Cloud Consul to manage configuration of my application (Spring Boot: v2.1.4.RELEASE)
In file 'application.yml' uploaded to Consul I have following configuration for Actuator:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: ALWAYS
```

which results in showing detailed information on /actuator/health endpoint.

When I change this property in Consul to value 'NEVER' while my application is running, the change is noticed and this property is refreshed what I can check in two places:

1) Logs

```
2019-05-15 16:07:52.355  INFO 11020 --- [TaskScheduler-1] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: CompositePropertySource {name='consul', propertySources=[ConsulFilesPropertySource {name='configuration/application.yml'}]}
2019-05-15 16:07:52.366  INFO 11020 --- [TaskScheduler-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-05-15 16:07:52.378  INFO 11020 --- [TaskScheduler-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Started application in 2.284 seconds (JVM running for 128.176)
2019-05-15 16:07:52.468  INFO 11020 --- [TaskScheduler-1] o.s.c.e.event.RefreshEventListener       : Refresh keys changed: [management.endpoint.health.show-details]
```

2) Endpoint `/actuator/configprops`

```
                "management.endpoint.health-org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointProperties": {
                    "prefix": "management.endpoint.health",
                    "properties": {
                        "showDetails": "NEVER",
                        "roles": []
                    }
                },
```

The problem is that `/actuator/health` endpoint is still providing health details ignoring changes regards to property "management.endpoint.health.show-details" made on runtime.

Is there any additional configuration that should be applied?

Comment: Just because you can change a value at runtime doesn't mean the use of it will be affected.

Comment: The question is: Is this a bug or maybe the desired behavior of the Actuator considering that endpoint '/actuator/configprops' returns the current value for this property?